# Using both std::string and QString interchangeably

Tags: c++, string, qt, stl, qstring

I use Qt extensively in a software system I'm working on for graphical and GUI components. However, for most internal algorithms and processing of data Qt plays a smaller role.

I'll often run into the need to convert from std::string to QString or visa versa. My inclination is to use std::string as much as possible and use QString **only** when I need to pass strings to Qt classes like those that work with the file system.

As I was programming this morning, it hit me that it may be bad design to have both std::string and QString sprinkled throughout my code. Should I completely switch to QString? Has anyone else run into this design choice?

Qt provides a lot of the same functionality of STL, but I'm still hesitant switching completely since Qt is less standardized and stable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, I've had this situation before. The program I worked on used Qt throughout, but I had to hook it up to a library that expected `std::string`. The benefit of `QString` is that it explicitly uses Unicode, while the C++ standard library makes no guarantees about encoding.

The solution was to convert at the boundary of this library with

```
QString toQString(std::string const &s)
{
    return QString::fromUtf8(s.c_str());
}

std::string fromQString(QString const &s)
{
    return std::string(s.toUtf8().data());
}
```

since the library produced `std::string`'s containing UTF-8.

What you seem to want is the exact opposite: use `std::string` throughout and convert at the Qt boundary. That seems perfectly ok; it takes a bit more work than always using `QString`, but you'll have to put in effort when you need a non-`QString`-accepting library anyway, and your non-GUI components don't depend on Qt (hurrah!).

Comment: `QString` has a method `toStdString()`. See here: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qstring.html#toStdString. To create a `QString` from `std::string` you can use this constructor: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qstring.html#QString-7

Comment: @yasourer: yes, but those depend on a globally set character encoding. These functions come from a library which got `std::string`'s from another library, always containing UTF-8.

Comment: You can improve those functions to work even if the strings contain embedded NULs, by passing the length as well - `return QString::fromUtf8(s.c_str(), s.size())` and `auto buf = s.toUtf8(); return std::string(buf.data(), buf.size());`.

Answer (score 6):

I would say use `std::string` in your program core, and convert them to `QString` when your are working on GUI part. I you ever want to change your GUI toolkit, that will be easier.